# An efficient way to calculate deltas in the DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to calculate the delta and I did it, but I'm using `itertuples` and I want to avoid use it...

There is an efficient way to do that? Take a look how I did it:

```
from numpy import append, around, array, float64
from numpy.random import uniform
from pandas import DataFrame

matrix = around(a=uniform(low=1.0, high=50.0, size=(10, 2)), decimals=2)
points = DataFrame(data=matrix, columns=['x', 'y'], dtype='float64')

x_column = points.columns.get_loc('x')
y_column = points.columns.get_loc('y')

x_delta = array(object=[], dtype=float64)
y_delta = array(object=[], dtype=float64)

for row, iterator in enumerate(iterable=points.itertuples(index=False, name='Point')):
    if row == 0:
        x_delta = append(arr=x_delta, values=0.0)
        y_delta = append(arr=y_delta, values=0.0)
    else:
        x_delta = append(arr=x_delta, values=iterator.x / points.iat[row - 1, x_column] - 1)
        y_delta = append(arr=y_delta, values=iterator.y / points.iat[row - 1, y_column] - 1)

x_delta = around(a=x_delta, decimals=2)
y_delta = around(a=y_delta, decimals=2)

points.insert(loc=points.shape[1], column='x_delta', value=x_delta)
points.insert(loc=points.shape[1], column='y_delta', value=y_delta)

print(points)

       x      y  x_delta  y_delta
0  26.08   1.37     0.00     0.00
1   8.34   6.82    -0.68     3.98
2  38.42  45.20     3.61     5.63
3   3.59  33.12    -0.91    -0.27
4  42.94  11.06    10.96    -0.67
5  31.99  17.38    -0.26     0.57
6   4.29  17.46    -0.87     0.00
7  19.68  22.28     3.59     0.28
8  27.55  12.98     0.40    -0.42
9  40.23   9.60     0.46    -0.26
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has `pct_change()` function which compares the current and prior element. You can achieve the same result with one line:

```
points[['x_delta', 'y_delta']] = points[['x', 'y']].pct_change().fillna(0).round(2)
```

The `fillna(0)` is to fix the first row which would otherwise return as NaN.

Comment: Awesome! exactly what i'm was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has the .diff() built in function.

> Calculates the difference of a Dataframe element compared with
> another element in the Dataframe (default is element in previous row).

```
delta_dataframe = original_dataframe.diff()
```

In this case delta_dataframe will give you the change between rows of the original_dataframe.